# Bypass policies when pushing but Prevent commits to Main Branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

If a user has `Bypass policies when pushing` enabled, how can I also configure it so that the same user is unable to commit directly to `Main` branch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. `Bypass policies when pushing` needs to be disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enable this permission on the repo level:

[image]

and disable on the branch level:

[image]